# Content-Disposition inline filename issue with internet explorer

Tags: java, internet-explorer, httpresponse

HTTPResponse object:

**final httpResponse**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Type: application/pdf
Content-Dis;filename*=utf-8''aproved.pdf
Expires: 0
Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: public
Content-Encoding: gzip
```

where the content-disposition is taking the filename as we are passing (approved.pdf)

But when we save the the pdf from the viewer in IE ,it saves as Downlaod.pdf(where Download is the servlet name)

The same usecase works fine in other browsers(chrome) by saving with the actual filename.pdf using the Content-Dispostion

Need help on this for IE browser.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be:

```
Content-Type: application/pdf
Content-Disposition: inline; filename="aproved.pdf"
```

?

Comment: according to RFC 6266/RFC 5987 standard encoding, the preferred encoding for all modern browsers:is "filename*=utf-8''" + filename